# How to make an ExpansionTile trailing Icon spin?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I've created an expansiontile and I've changed the original trailing icon to an svg icon which I customized. Anytime I click the expansion tile... everything works but the new svg trailing icon doesnt spin like the original trailing icon. Please how do I fix this?

code below

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

class ExpansionTileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String toptitle;
  final List<Widget> children;
  const ExpansionTileCard({Key key, this.toptitle, this.children})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border:
                    new Border(bottom: new BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
            child: new Row(
              children: [
                new Expanded(
                  flex: 9,
                  child: new Container(
                    child: new Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ExpansionTile(
                          title: Text(
                            toptitle,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                letterSpacing: -1,
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          children: children,
                          childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
                          iconColor: Colors.green,
                          trailing: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'assets/icons/textmessage.svg',
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet/resource that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: i've added the code for my expansion file class in my original post. please review. NOTE; the code is fully functional, the svg asset doesnt just spin like the original expansion tile icon

Answer (score 9):

While we don't provide `trailing` on `ExpansionTile` it uses the default behavior of it.

We are passing a widget into `trailing` and we need to control it. In order to do that, we need to check if `ExpansionTile` is expanded or not, the `onExpansionChanged` call back will provide this value. To handle animation we can use many widgets like `Transform`, `RotatedBox`, `AnimatedRotation`... In this `ExpansionTileCard` widget will be extended from `StatefulWidget` .

**Steps**

1. convert to `StatefulWidget`
2. create a bool inside state class to check the Expanded-state.
    `bool _isExpanded = false;`
3. change value on `onExpansionChanged`

```dart
     onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                           setState(() {
                             _isExpanded = value;
                           });
                         },
```

4. assign your widget on `trailing` by wrapping animation widget or just check the state return two widget

   - `_isExpanded? ExpandedWidget:NormalViewWidget()`
   - ```dart
        trailing: AnimatedRotation(  /// you can use different widget for animation
                          turns: _isExpanded ? .5 : 0,
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                          child: CustomWidget()// your svgImage here
                        ),
     ```

**Widget State**

```dart
class _ExpansionTileCardState extends State<ExpansionTileCard> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 9,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ExpansionTile(
                          onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _isExpanded = value;
                            });
                          },
                          title: Text(
                            widget.toptitle,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                letterSpacing: -1,
                                fontSize: 19,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          children: widget.children,
                          childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
                          iconColor: Colors.green,
                          trailing: AnimatedRotation(
                            turns: _isExpanded ? .5 : 0,
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            child:  SvgPicture.asset(
                           'assets/icons/textmessage.svg',
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```